# MKMapView with multiple overlays memory-issue

Tags: ios, memory, mkmapview, mkoverlay, mkpolygon

There seems to be an "issue" with overlays and the `MapKit`. Unlike annotations, overlays aren't reused and therefore when adding multiple overlays would cause memory-problems on a real device. I've had this problem multiple times. So my question is, how can I reuse the MKOverlay and so improve the performance of overlays on `MapKit`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Answer to this is not "reusing" but to draw them all in to one `MKOverlayView` and then draw that on the map.

Multiple `MKPolygons`, `MKOverlays` etc. cause heavy memory-usage when drawing on the map. This is due the NOT reusing of overlays by `MapKit`. As annotations have the `reuseWithIdentifier`, overlays however don't. Each overlay creates a new layer as a `MKOverlayView` on the map with the overlay in it. In that way memory-usage will rise quite fast and map-usage becomes... let's say sluggish to almost impossible.

Therefore there is a work-around: Instead of plotting each overlay individually, you can add all of the `MKOverlays` to one `MKOverlayView`. This way you're in fact creating only one `MKOverlayView` and thus there's no need to reuse.

*This is the work-around, in this case for `MKPolygons` but should be not very different for others like `MKCircles` etc.*

create a class: `MultiPolygon` (subclass of `NSObject`)

in `MultiPolygon.h`:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h> //Add import MapKit

@interface MultiPolygon : NSObject <MKOverlay> {
 NSArray *_polygons;
 MKMapRect _boundingMapRect;
}

- (id)initWithPolygons:(NSArray *)polygons;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *polygons;

@end
```

in `MultiPolygon.m`:

```
@implementation MultiPolygon

@synthesize polygons = _polygons;

- (id)initWithPolygons:(NSArray *)polygons
{
 if (self = [super init]) {
    _polygons = [polygons copy];

    NSUInteger polyCount = [_polygons count];
     if (polyCount) {
        _boundingMapRect = [[_polygons objectAtIndex:0] boundingMapRect];
        NSUInteger i;
        for (i = 1; i < polyCount; i++) {
            _boundingMapRect = MKMapRectUnion(_boundingMapRect, [[_polygons objectAtIndex:i] boundingMapRect]);
        }
    }
 }
 return self;
}

- (MKMapRect)boundingMapRect
{
 return _boundingMapRect;
}

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
 return MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMidX(_boundingMapRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(_boundingMapRect)));
}

@end
```

Now create a class: `MultiPolygonView` (subclass of `MKOverlayPathView`)

in `MultiPolygonView.h`:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MultiPolygonView : MKOverlayPathView

@end
```

In `MultiPolygonView.m`:

```
#import "MultiPolygon.h"  //Add import "MultiPolygon.h"


@implementation MultiPolygonView


- (CGPathRef)polyPath:(MKPolygon *)polygon

{
 MKMapPoint *points = [polygon points];
 NSUInteger pointCount = [polygon pointCount];
 NSUInteger i;

 if (pointCount < 3)
     return NULL;

 CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

 for (MKPolygon *interiorPolygon in polygon.interiorPolygons) {
     CGPathRef interiorPath = [self polyPath:interiorPolygon];
     CGPathAddPath(path, NULL, interiorPath);
     CGPathRelease(interiorPath);
 }

 CGPoint relativePoint = [self pointForMapPoint:points[0]];
 CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, relativePoint.x, relativePoint.y);
 for (i = 1; i < pointCount; i++) {
     relativePoint = [self pointForMapPoint:points[i]];
     CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, relativePoint.x, relativePoint.y);
 }

 return path;
}

- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
      zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
      inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
 MultiPolygon *multiPolygon = (MultiPolygon *)self.overlay;
 for (MKPolygon *polygon in multiPolygon.polygons) {
    CGPathRef path = [self polyPath:polygon];
     if (path) {
         [self applyFillPropertiesToContext:context atZoomScale:zoomScale];
         CGContextBeginPath(context);
         CGContextAddPath(context, path);
         CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathEOFill);
         [self applyStrokePropertiesToContext:context atZoomScale:zoomScale];
         CGContextBeginPath(context);
         CGContextAddPath(context, path);
         CGContextStrokePath(context);
         CGPathRelease(path);
     }
 }
}

@end
```

To us it import `MultiPolygon.h` and `MultiPolygonView.h` in your ViewController

Create one polygon from all:
As an example I've got an array with polygons: `polygonsInArray`.

```
MultiPolygon *allPolygonsInOne = [[MultiPolygon alloc] initWithPolygons:polygonsInArray];
```

Add the allPolygonsInOne to the mapView:

```
[mapView addOverlay:allPolygonsInOne];
```

Also change your `viewForOverlay` method:

```
-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{

 if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MultiPolygon class]]) {
     MultiPolygonView *polygonsView = [[MultiPolygonView alloc] initWithOverlay:(MultiPolygon*)overlay];
     polygonsView.fillColor = [[UIColor magentaColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8];
     polygonsView.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8];
     polygonsView.lineWidth = 1;
     return polygonsView;
 }
 else {
   return nil;
 }

}
```

And this greatly reduced memory usage for multiple overlays on the `mapView`. You're not reusing now because only one `OverlayView` is drawn. So no need to reuse.

Comment: I still can't adapt this to MKCircle example :/

Comment: What value should I give _boundinMapRect if I adapt this for MKPolyline?

Comment: This is not a bad idea at all. Is it also possible to set colors per polygon/circle????

Comment: i will suggest - `github it`.

Comment: @MQoder before you render each polygon in method `- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context` in class `MultiPolygonView`, set color to the context for each polygon. Of couse, you should inherite `MKOverlayRenderer` instead of `MKOverlayView` now, because `MKOverlayView` is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

A **Swift 4** version of the Objective-C code posted by @wkberg:

MultiPolygon.swift:

```
import MapKit

/// A concatenation of multiple polygons to allow a single overlay to be drawn in the map,
/// which will consume less resources
class MultiPolygon: NSObject, MKOverlay {
    var polygons: [MKPolygon]?

    var boundingMapRect: MKMapRect

    init(polygons: [MKPolygon]?) {
        self.polygons = polygons
        self.boundingMapRect = MKMapRect.null

        super.init()

        guard let pols = polygons else { return }
        for (index, polygon) in pols.enumerated() {
            if index == 0 { self.boundingMapRect = polygon.boundingMapRect; continue }
            boundingMapRect = boundingMapRect.union(polygon.boundingMapRect)
        }
    }

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return MKMapPoint(x: boundingMapRect.midX, y: boundingMapRect.maxY).coordinate
    }
}
```

MultiPolygonPathRenderer.swift:

```
import MapKit

/// A MKOverlayPathRenderer that can draw a concatenation of multiple polygons as a single polygon
/// This will consume less resources
class MultiPolygonPathRenderer: MKOverlayPathRenderer {
    /**
     Returns a `CGPath` equivalent to this polygon in given renderer.

     - parameter polygon: MKPolygon defining coordinates that will be drawn.

     - returns: Path equivalent to this polygon in given renderer.
     */
    func polyPath(for polygon: MKPolygon?) -> CGPath? {
        guard let polygon = polygon else { return nil }
        let points = polygon.points()

        if polygon.pointCount < 3 { return nil }
        let pointCount = polygon.pointCount

        let path = CGMutablePath()

        if let interiorPolygons = polygon.interiorPolygons {
            for interiorPolygon in interiorPolygons {
                guard let interiorPath = polyPath(for: interiorPolygon) else { continue }
                path.addPath(interiorPath, transform: .identity)
            }
        }

        let startPoint = point(for: points[0])
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: startPoint.x, y: startPoint.y), transform: .identity)

        for i in 1..<pointCount {
            let nextPoint = point(for: points[i])
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: nextPoint.x, y: nextPoint.y), transform: .identity)
        }

        return path
    }

    /// Draws the overlay’s contents at the specified location on the map.
    override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext) {
        // Taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17673411

        guard let multiPolygon = self.overlay as? MultiPolygon else { return }
        guard let polygons = multiPolygon.polygons else { return }

        for polygon in polygons {
            guard let path = self.polyPath(for: polygon) else { continue }
            self.applyFillProperties(to: context, atZoomScale: zoomScale)
            context.beginPath()
            context.addPath(path)
            context.drawPath(using: CGPathDrawingMode.eoFill)
            self.applyStrokeProperties(to: context, atZoomScale: zoomScale)
            context.beginPath()
            context.addPath(path)
            context.strokePath()
        }
    }
}
```

Usage - Adding the overlay to your `MKMapView`:

```
// Add the overlay to mapView
let polygonsArray: [MKPolygon] = self.buildMKPolygons()
let multiPolygons = MultiPolygon.init(polygons: polygonsArray)
self.mapView.addOverlay(multiPolygons)
```

Usage - Implementing the viewForOverlay in your `MKMapViewDelegate`:

```
// Method viewForOverlay:
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if overlay is MultiPolygon {
        let polygonRenderer = MultiPolygonPathRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        polygonRenderer.lineWidth = 0.5
        polygonRenderer.strokeColor = .mainGreen
        polygonRenderer.miterLimit = 2.0
        polygonRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.mainGreen.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
        return polygonRenderer
    }

    return MKOverlayRenderer()
}
```

Comment: This is now part of Apple Mapkit - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmultipolyline