# Draw multiple MKCircle in MapView iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk, geometry, mkpolygon

I want to draw multiple MKCircle in mapview but it cause memory problem. I found a solution to reduce memory consommation but it's for MKPolygon in this link [MKMapView with multiple overlays memory-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673410/mkmapview-with-multiple-overlays-memory-issue)
My problem is that i want to use it for MKCircle and i don't know how to. Can anyone help me to customize the code to work with MKCircle.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know it's a "memory problem" exactly (what errors do you get)?  How many MKCircles are you adding?  Show the code that adds them and the viewForOverlay or rendererForOverlay.

Comment: The number of MKCircle depend on the number of messages that the user receive. And i have the draw in the map for one message an MKCircle and an Overlay that will contain the picture of the sender. When there is a lot of overlays in MapView the memory consummation increase and the application crash i have also lag when zooming. It's why i choose to implement the solution in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673410/mkmapview-with-multiple-overlays-memory-issue but this solution use MKPlygon not MKCirle and i wan to change it.

Comment: any update on this issue ??